# Broken references in Virtocommerce vc-community-webadmin v1.13

Tags: azure, e-commerce, virtocommerce

I just started using **Virtocommerce v.1.13** and have two questions for developers and two tips for those who is the newbie as me.

**The problem**

- I downloaded vc-community-webadmin from Github/webadmin
- then I open solution and run Nuget for restoring all packages need
- nevertheless, when I try to build the solution I found out that **some references are broken:**

> - Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client
> - Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core
> - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

**[[see fig. 1](http://content.screencast.com/users/Romakosh/folders/Jing/media/cbf76ea5-9403-4eca-aff2-b471c01d1f86/2015-02-11_1740.png)]**

**Workaround**

- I downloaded microsoft.applicationserver.caching.*.dll, put them into the package/.fix folder and referred them from .\src\Extensions\Cache\AppFabricCacheService\ project
- As for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, it is actually present in the package folder, but is not referred properly.
- Moreover, there are two dll in the package folder that can be referred. They have the same versions but different size. **[[see fig 2](http://content.screencast.com/users/Romakosh/folders/Jing/media/e7ce4ccb-3da8-4e7e-981b-d9d83fcb111d/2015-02-11_1805.png)]**
- I used the .\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.1.7.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll one.
- After that the solution were built without errors.

**Question**

- Dear VC-team, is that my fault or there is a defect in the VC-project files?
- I have Windows 8.1 and VS 2012 update 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching.Core and Caching.Client were supposed to be installed with Azure SDK v2.2. I have added these assemblies to Shared folder and updated references.

Reference to StorageClient was invalid. I have fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for fixing! Will wait for 2.2